# Poor performance postgres left join when using between condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I am using Postgres 11 and I have two tables, mouse_move (12805080 rows) and app_event (2983971 rows), that I want to left join with the following query

```
SELECT *
   FROM mouse_move
     left JOIN app_event ON 
     mouse_move.uuid::text = app_event.uuid::text AND 
     mouse_move.db_name::text = app_event.db_name::text and
     mouse_move.event_timestamp >= app_event.start_timestamp AND mouse_move.event_timestamp <= app_event.end_timestamp
```

The tables have multiple-columns indexes with the columns used in the query.
The query runs very slowly (22 min) compared to a simpler inner join with the same condition (~2 min). I had a look at the explain: most of the time is spent in the Merge Join and the rows for the materialized step are underestimated by the planner by a huge factor. I'm not an expert of DBs, so I would like to know if there is anything that can help improving the performance. Especially, if adding any index or statistics can improve the quality of the plan. As more data are collected, it seems to me that this query will not scale up. Thanks

```
"Gather  (cost=1001.12..4391658.54 rows=12805080 width=253) (actual time=0.348..1834200.357 rows=12805080 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  Buffers: shared hit=494918 read=437424"
"  I/O Timings: read=26662.468"
"  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1.12..3110150.54 rows=5335450 width=253) (actual time=1.751..1829903.695 rows=4268360 loops=3)"
"        Merge Cond: (((mouse_move.uuid)::text = (app_event.uuid)::text) AND ((mouse_move.db_name)::text = (app_event.db_name)::text))"
"        Join Filter: ((mouse_move.event_timestamp >= app_event.start_timestamp) AND (mouse_move.event_timestamp <= app_event.end_timestamp))"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2982395649"
"        Buffers: shared hit=494918 read=437424"
"        I/O Timings: read=26662.468"
"        ->  Parallel Index Scan using mouse_move_idx_all_timestamp on mouse_move  (cost=0.56..1630981.79 rows=5335450 width=105) (actual time=1.694..14439.293 rows=4268360 loops=3)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=162579 read=383277"
"              I/O Timings: read=26031.084"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.56..489657.96 rows=2983971 width=148) (actual time=0.015..386371.252 rows=2986813075 loops=3)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=332339 read=54147"
"              I/O Timings: read=631.385"
"              ->  Index Scan using app_event_idx_all_timestamp on app_event  (cost=0.56..482198.03 rows=2983971 width=148) (actual time=0.011..1660.860 rows=2983971 loops=3)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=332339 read=54147"
"                    I/O Timings: read=631.385"
"Planning Time: 1.019 ms"
"Execution Time: 1835802.069 ms"
```

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Gather",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Startup Cost": 1001.12,
      "Total Cost": 4391658.54,
      "Plan Rows": 12805080,
      "Plan Width": 253,
      "Actual Startup Time": 0.335,
      "Actual Total Time": 1799731.441,
      "Actual Rows": 12805080,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Output": [
        "mouse_move.db_name",
        "mouse_move.uuid",
        "mouse_move.event_id",
        "mouse_move.event_timestamp",
        "mouse_move.duration",
        "mouse_move.distance",
        "mouse_move.distance_mm",
        "mouse_move.distance_on_eyetracker_screen",
        "mouse_move.distance_mm_on_eyetracker_screen",
        "app_event.db_name",
        "app_event.uuid",
        "app_event.start_timestamp",
        "app_event.end_timestamp",
        "app_event.window_process",
        "app_event.window_class",
        "app_event.window_title",
        "app_event.app_view_alias",
        "app_event.browser_url",
        "app_event.window_x",
        "app_event.window_y",
        "app_event.window_width",
        "app_event.window_height",
        "app_event.event_id"
      ],
      "Workers Planned": 2,
      "Workers Launched": 2,
      "Single Copy": false,
      "Shared Hit Blocks": 525437,
      "Shared Read Blocks": 403511,
      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
      "I/O Read Time": 18881.913,
      "I/O Write Time": 0,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Merge Join",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Join Type": "Left",
          "Startup Cost": 1.12,
          "Total Cost": 3110150.54,
          "Plan Rows": 5335450,
          "Plan Width": 253,
          "Actual Startup Time": 0.073,
          "Actual Total Time": 1795390.268,
          "Actual Rows": 4268360,
          "Actual Loops": 3,
          "Output": [
            "mouse_move.db_name",
            "mouse_move.uuid",
            "mouse_move.event_id",
            "mouse_move.event_timestamp",
            "mouse_move.duration",
            "mouse_move.distance",
            "mouse_move.distance_mm",
            "mouse_move.distance_on_eyetracker_screen",
            "mouse_move.distance_mm_on_eyetracker_screen",
            "app_event.db_name",
            "app_event.uuid",
            "app_event.start_timestamp",
            "app_event.end_timestamp",
            "app_event.window_process",
            "app_event.window_class",
            "app_event.window_title",
            "app_event.app_view_alias",
            "app_event.browser_url",
            "app_event.window_x",
            "app_event.window_y",
            "app_event.window_width",
            "app_event.window_height",
            "app_event.event_id"
          ],
          "Inner Unique": false,
          "Merge Cond": "(((mouse_move.uuid)::text = (app_event.uuid)::text) AND ((mouse_move.db_name)::text = (app_event.db_name)::text))",
          "Join Filter": "((mouse_move.event_timestamp >= app_event.start_timestamp) AND (mouse_move.event_timestamp <= app_event.end_timestamp))",
          "Rows Removed by Join Filter": 2982395649,
          "Shared Hit Blocks": 525437,
          "Shared Read Blocks": 403511,
          "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
          "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
          "Local Read Blocks": 0,
          "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
          "Local Written Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
          "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
          "I/O Read Time": 18881.913,
          "I/O Write Time": 0,
          "Workers": [
            {
              "Worker Number": 0,
              "Actual Startup Time": 0.083,
              "Actual Total Time": 1795519.049,
              "Actual Rows": 4261870,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 173782,
              "Shared Read Blocks": 136197,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
              "I/O Read Time": 6433.326,
              "I/O Write Time": 0
            },
            {
              "Worker Number": 1,
              "Actual Startup Time": 0.109,
              "Actual Total Time": 1795409.518,
              "Actual Rows": 4262034,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 175020,
              "Shared Read Blocks": 134574,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
              "I/O Read Time": 6360.393,
              "I/O Write Time": 0
            }
          ],
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": true,
              "Scan Direction": "Forward",
              "Index Name": "mouse_move_idx_all_timestamp",
              "Relation Name": "mouse_move",
              "Schema": "public",
              "Alias": "mouse_move",
              "Startup Cost": 0.56,
              "Total Cost": 1630981.79,
              "Plan Rows": 5335450,
              "Plan Width": 105,
              "Actual Startup Time": 0.007,
              "Actual Total Time": 10972.966,
              "Actual Rows": 4268360,
              "Actual Loops": 3,
              "Output": [
                "mouse_move.db_name",
                "mouse_move.uuid",
                "mouse_move.event_id",
                "mouse_move.event_timestamp",
                "mouse_move.duration",
                "mouse_move.distance",
                "mouse_move.distance_mm",
                "mouse_move.distance_on_eyetracker_screen",
                "mouse_move.distance_mm_on_eyetracker_screen"
              ],
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 251111,
              "Shared Read Blocks": 292452,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
              "I/O Read Time": 18466.31,
              "I/O Write Time": 0,
              "Workers": [
                {
                  "Worker Number": 0,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.008,
                  "Actual Total Time": 11115.945,
                  "Actual Rows": 4261870,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 83272,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 98245,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                  "I/O Read Time": 6293.593,
                  "I/O Write Time": 0
                },
                {
                  "Worker Number": 1,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.007,
                  "Actual Total Time": 11074.816,
                  "Actual Rows": 4262034,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 83899,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 97233,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                  "I/O Read Time": 6217.653,
                  "I/O Write Time": 0
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Materialize",
              "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Startup Cost": 0.56,
              "Total Cost": 489657.96,
              "Plan Rows": 2983971,
              "Plan Width": 148,
              "Actual Startup Time": 0.013,
              "Actual Total Time": 379317.533,
              "Actual Rows": 2986821333,
              "Actual Loops": 3,
              "Output": [
                "app_event.db_name",
                "app_event.uuid",
                "app_event.start_timestamp",
                "app_event.end_timestamp",
                "app_event.window_process",
                "app_event.window_class",
                "app_event.window_title",
                "app_event.app_view_alias",
                "app_event.browser_url",
                "app_event.window_x",
                "app_event.window_y",
                "app_event.window_width",
                "app_event.window_height",
                "app_event.event_id"
              ],
              "Shared Hit Blocks": 274326,
              "Shared Read Blocks": 111059,
              "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
              "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
              "Local Read Blocks": 0,
              "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
              "Local Written Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
              "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
              "I/O Read Time": 415.603,
              "I/O Write Time": 0,
              "Workers": [
                {
                  "Worker Number": 0,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.017,
                  "Actual Total Time": 379314.173,
                  "Actual Rows": 2993043689,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 90510,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 37952,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                  "I/O Read Time": 139.733,
                  "I/O Write Time": 0
                },
                {
                  "Worker Number": 1,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.015,
                  "Actual Total Time": 380272.5,
                  "Actual Rows": 2969781288,
                  "Actual Loops": 1,
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 91121,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 37341,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                  "I/O Read Time": 142.74,
                  "I/O Write Time": 0
                }
              ],
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                  "Index Name": "app_event_idx_all_timestamp",
                  "Relation Name": "app_event",
                  "Schema": "public",
                  "Alias": "app_event",
                  "Startup Cost": 0.56,
                  "Total Cost": 482198.03,
                  "Plan Rows": 2983971,
                  "Plan Width": 148,
                  "Actual Startup Time": 0.011,
                  "Actual Total Time": 1656.429,
                  "Actual Rows": 2983971,
                  "Actual Loops": 3,
                  "Output": [
                    "app_event.db_name",
                    "app_event.uuid",
                    "app_event.start_timestamp",
                    "app_event.end_timestamp",
                    "app_event.window_process",
                    "app_event.window_class",
                    "app_event.window_title",
                    "app_event.app_view_alias",
                    "app_event.browser_url",
                    "app_event.window_x",
                    "app_event.window_y",
                    "app_event.window_width",
                    "app_event.window_height",
                    "app_event.event_id"
                  ],
                  "Shared Hit Blocks": 274326,
                  "Shared Read Blocks": 111059,
                  "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                  "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                  "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                  "I/O Read Time": 415.603,
                  "I/O Write Time": 0,
                  "Workers": [
                    {
                      "Worker Number": 0,
                      "Actual Startup Time": 0.014,
                      "Actual Total Time": 1590.19,
                      "Actual Rows": 2983971,
                      "Actual Loops": 1,
                      "Shared Hit Blocks": 90510,
                      "Shared Read Blocks": 37952,
                      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                      "I/O Read Time": 139.733,
                      "I/O Write Time": 0
                    },
                    {
                      "Worker Number": 1,
                      "Actual Startup Time": 0.012,
                      "Actual Total Time": 1646.447,
                      "Actual Rows": 2983971,
                      "Actual Loops": 1,
                      "Shared Hit Blocks": 91121,
                      "Shared Read Blocks": 37341,
                      "Shared Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                      "Shared Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Hit Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Read Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Dirtied Blocks": 0,
                      "Local Written Blocks": 0,
                      "Temp Read Blocks": 0,
                      "Temp Written Blocks": 0,
                      "I/O Read Time": 142.74,
                      "I/O Write Time": 0
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Planning Time": 1.012,
    "Triggers": [],
    "Execution Time": 1801335.068
  }
]
```

UPDATE After scaisEdge suggestion about removing cast and change index:
Same performance.
[image: plan]

Comment: If you care about performance and want to use indexes, don't convert types in the `on` clause.  Fix the data so the type conversions are not necessary.

Comment: The JSON format of the execution plan is not intended for humans. Please show us the plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, timing, format text)`

Comment: Done. Anyway, I use https://dalibo.github.io/pev2/#/plan to understand of the json

Comment: By the way, uuid and db_name are varchar, the timestamps are bigint